# Apache : CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache, .htaccess, svg

i am calling some svg image in my website from some other using jquery post i get below error in console

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://abc/svgpaths/sample.svg. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).**

i have below paramter set in my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

i also tested  a2enmod headers in putty it showed me Module headers already enabled

But when i use Ip instead of domain name

for eg : https://1.2.3.5/svgpaths/sample.svg

i get below error in console **net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE**

i could not figure out what to do to fix it please guide me with issue.

**Js code to call svg from other server**

**Case 1**
**with ip** (differnt ssl on main and subdomain)

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL("https://1.2.3.4/svgpaths/sample.svg", function(objects, options){
            var object = new fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
            object.set({
                fill: '#000000',
                selectable:false
            });
```

Error : ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

**Case 2**
When called with differnet subdomain :(subdomain resolves to same ip as above case 1 , i recently pointed subdomain so is there somesetting in confi file that i missed )

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL("https://abd.maindomain.com/svgpaths/sample.svg", function(objects, options){
            var object = new fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
            object.set({
                fill: '#000000',
                selectable:false
            });
```

Error :Apache : CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing

Comment: if you are using chrome, then close chrome, it's background processes, and start again. Sometimes chrome show this error by caching the domain name instead of ip address.

Comment: no it did not worked, issue was that i added domain name later before it was just ip

Comment: why you are using post method when you are just calling images from another website/domain, shouldn't it be a get method? besides the domain you are calling from yours, should be core enabled for your domain.

Comment: updated code bro , please check

Answer (score 2):

Adding this code in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf fixed it for me.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you don't have an active SSL certificate. You can test that by going to the actual request URL.

As well including the actual HTTP response can be helpful (can be found in the network tab of chrome's developer tools).

PS. I would've responded with a comment but that's broken on mobile

Comment: it has active ssl on both